# Extraiga eficientemente las líneas de un archivo que contienen una cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x

Para resumir un archivo quiero extraer de una archivo tex sola lineas que contienen `\section, \subsection, \subsubsection, \begin, \end` y `\item`. Intenté hacerlo con el codigo siguiente :

```
>>> with open(fr_13_regions.tex,'r') as f:
...     targets = [line for line in f if '\' in line]
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    targets = [line for line in f if '\' in line]
                                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

El archivo esta [ahi](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kdbbsrhdwnvx) pero aqui esta un ejemplo :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}


\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\SetPaperName{%
  \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{26}{0}\bfseries
  La France des 13 régions%
}

\SetPaperLocation{}
\SetPaperSlogan{Sous la direction de L. Carroué}
\SetPaperPrice{antoine.compagnie@gmail.com}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}

\headline{Ile-de-France}
\section{La Région-capitale : une place et un rôle exceptionnels}
\subsection{Une longue construction historique}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que cometes es no escapar el símbolo \. Por escapar nos referimos a que una barra `\` dentro de una [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) se usa para expresar que el siguiente símbolo o letra debería interpretarse de forma literal y que no es algo "especial". En este caso, ya que las barras son símbolos especiales, `'\'` da error porque debería ser `'\\'` (de esta manera se le dice al código con la primera barra que debería interpretar la segunda barra como algo normal, no como algo especial).

```
with open(fr_13_regions.tex,'r') as f:
    targets = [line for line in f if '\\' in line]
```

Pero si quieres una mejor respuesta, para limitar los resultados a solo 
\section, \subsection, \subsubsection, \begin, \end y \item, yo lo haría así:

```
with open(fr_13_regions.tex,'r') as f:
    targets = [line for line in f if line.startswith(("\\section", "\\subsection", "\\subsubsection", "\\begin", "\\end", "\\item"))]
```

Comment: Y en tu segunda solución olvidaste también escapar las barras :-)

Comment: Dentro de una tupla como es ese `startswith` no es necesario escapar las barras. Acabo de comprobarlo y no da ningún error al ejecutarse.

Comment: Sí lo es. No tiene qué ver que sea dentro de una tupla o dentro de una list comprehension. Lo que importa es que aparezca dentro de una cadena (entre comillas). Dentro de las comillas la barra \ es especial, y su significado depende de qué carácter vaya despues. En algunos casos puede no causar problema (ej: `\section`) porque `\s` no representa nada y por tanto la barra se interpreta literal, pero en otros dará problemas, por ejemplo `\begin` pues `\b` representa el ascii 8 (bell) y por tanto estás usando una cadena distinta de la que pensabas.

Comment: Por completar, si quieres no andar pendiente de duplicar la barra dentro de las comillas, puedes poner una `r` antes de las comillas, así: `r"\section", r"\begin"` etc Esta `r` significa "raw" y en ese caso python no da significado especial a la barra.

Comment: Tienes razón, por un momento no he pensado con claridad y me he liado con otro lenguaje.

Comment: Muchas gracias para su repuesta. Sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error `NameError: name 'fr_13_regions' is not defined`

Comment: Por el código que nos enseñaste, supuse que el nombre de tu archivo estaba guardado en una variable con ese nombre. Para solucionarlo, simplemente ahí escribe el nombre de tu archivo como primer argumento de la función `open`. Por ejemplo: `with open("prueba.txt",'r') as f:`

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Y como puedo escribir el resultado en un nuevo archivo ? Probé `print(targets)` pero después me da todo sobre una linea sola.

Comment: Abre una nueva pregunta para un nuevo problema. Esas son las normas de este sitio.